# How to import special less file form another meteor package?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, less

For example， I want to import @gray-lighter color into a less file from varables.less from twbs：bootstrap package how to do this my loading.less file is:

```
@import 'bootstrap.variables.less';

.loading {
padding: 48px 0;
text-align: center;

i {
  color: @gray-lighter;
}
}
```

But there is a error:

```
C:\Users\sheng\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
                                            throw(ex);
                                                  ^
Error: EPERM, unlink 'G:\workspace\meteor-admin-lte\.meteor\local\build\programs'
at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\sheng\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:15)
at Object.rm_recursive (C:\tools\fs\files.js:270:9)
at Object.files.rename (C:\tools\fs\files.js:1406:13)
at Object.files.renameDirAlmostAtomically (C:\tools\fs\files.js:812:11)
at Builder.complete (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:571:13)
at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1993:13
at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2010:7
at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2287:22
at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:268:13
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:261:29
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:259:18
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:250:23
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:249:19)
at Object.exports.bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2128:31)
at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:551:36
at time (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:232:28)
at Function.run (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:377:12)
at bundleApp (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:541:34)
at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:594:35)
at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:858:28)
at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:396:12
- - - - -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap meteor package don't use Less files. These are just .css and .js files and they should be added to the app when you add the package. If you need Less files you probably want to create your own build or find some other package.

As you can se here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/package.js there are just two files added + fonts.